# Prevent from display hours input - DateTimeType

Tags: symfony, datetime, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

I know about options like *with_seconds* or *with_minutes*, but im looking for something to stop rendering my hours input in DateTimeType field. For now it looks like this: 
[image]

My question how is possible to avoid this input in second row ? 
Maybe with form themes, but i want to consider with another option.

My RegistrationFormType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;


class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('sex', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => array(
            'Mężczyzna' => 'Mężczyzna',
            'Kobieta' => 'Kobieta'
        ),
        'expanded'=> true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'required' => true
    ));
    $builder->add('birthday_date', DateTimeType::class, array(
        'placeholder' => array(
            'year' => 'Year', 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day'
        ),
        'years' => range(1960, 2017),
        'with_minutes' => false,
        'hours' => array()
    ));
    $builder->add('about_me', TextareaType::class);
}
public function getParent()
{
    return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
}
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'app_user_registration';
}
}
```

I'm using FOSUserBundle, so this is my form template for now:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Thanks you in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Why using DateTimeType if you don't need time ?
Try using DateType or BirthdayType ([doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html)
)